# How to mock injected objects with Hilt?

Tags: android, kotlin

Consider the below example

```
@Singleton
class LoginModel @Inject contractor(private val userModel:UserModel){

}

@Config(application = HiltTestApplication::class)
@HiltAndroidTest
class LoginModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @Inject
    lateinit var loginModel: LoginModel

    @Before
    open fun setup() {
        hiltRule.inject()
    }
}
```

How to mock `UserModel` inside the `LoginModel` **without manually constructing `LoginModel`**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is simple. You have to deliver two different versions of UserModel - production, and mock in tests.
You can do it by following these steps.

1. Provide UserModel thru hilt module, annotating by Inject is not enough
2. Accordingly to your needs :

Replace that module just in single test sheet https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-testing#replace-binding-manually

Or

Replace in all tests
https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-testing#replace-binding

In both cases you will end up with module which return mock in binding.

Cheers

Comment: But creating a different version of this UserModel is not going to be mocked? What if I wanted to @Mock the UserModel, so I would be able to mock the response from the model?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, Jakub for the link. Here is my favorite way of doing it

```
@UninstallModules(AnalyticsModule::class)
@HiltAndroidTest
class SettingsActivityTest {

  @BindValue @JvmField
  val analyticsService: AnalyticsService = FakeAnalyticsService()

  ...
}
```